# Dynamic Matrix using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am working on HMM algorithm.As I am new to python I wanted to know how i can dynamically change the dimension of a matrix using numpy.

I am getting inconsistent output with numpy resize.

```
1    [[ 1.]]

 2   [[ 1.  1.]]
    [[ 2.  1.]]

  3  [[ 2.  1.  0.]
     [ 0.  0.  1.]]

   4 [[ 2.  1.  0.  0.]
     [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
     [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]

Here in fourth i should get output as 
     [[ 2.  1.  0.  0.]
     [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
     [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

Code :-

```
   with open("SampleFile.tsv") as tsvfile:
        tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
        wordindex = 0
        postagindex = 0
        flag = 0
        for line in tsvreader:
            if len(line) > 0:
                if line[1] not in words:
                    wcount += 1
                    flag = 1
                    #wordlikelihoodmatrix.resize(poscount, wcount)
                    words.append(line[1])
                    wordindex = words.index(line[1])
                else:
                    wordindex = words.index(line[1])

                if line[2] not in poslist:
                    poscount += 1
                    flag = 1
                    #wordlikelihoodmatrix.resize(poscount, wcount)
                    poslist.append(line[2])
                    posindex = poslist.index(line[2])
                else:
                    posindex = poslist.index(line[2])

                if flag == 1:
                    wordlikelihoodmatrix.resize(poscount, wcount)
                    flag = 0

                wordlikelihoodmatrix[posindex][wordindex] +=1
                print wordlikelihoodmatrix;
```

Can anybody suggest where i am going wrong while resizing or any other way to get the expected output without using numpy ?

Comment: ```a.resize(new_shape) which fills with zeros instead of repeated copies of a.``` from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html). But i hope you realize the overhead of these operations (compared to other data-structures as lists; it's basically a copy of the whole array).

Comment: @sascha i am facing above problem while resizing..i have edited the question for better understanding.

Comment: Show us the code...

Comment: @AndrewJaffe here i am reading the tsv file and on the basis of some condition i am incrementing the value in the row and column,it gives me the wrong output instead of what i expected.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe If the above resizing thing can be achieved without bumpy, then also it will do it for me.

Comment: I can't connect the print output to the code.  How would you do this with lists?

Comment: @hpaulj Thats why i didn't show the code as its part of a bigger solution. You can just try to see whether can you get the above output by hardcoding 1's on that positions

Comment: `rezize` in either form is not widely used in `numpy` code.  The various forms of `concatenate` (`stack`) give more control over the content of the new larger arrays.  But appending to a list is a better way of building an array iteratively.